# An isoperimetric problem with the "wrong" perimeter

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation

There is a scarcity on the web of examples of solving constrained problems using the calculus of variations.  Yes, everybody shows how to prove the shortest distance between two points is a straight line, and you can find the classical isoperimetric problem and the brachistrone, but that seems to be about it.

As a practice problem, say you were asked to find the curve $y(x)$ of length $\pi$ going from $(x=-1,y=0)$ to $(x=+1,y=0)$ that maximizes the area between the curve and the $X$ axis:
$$A = \int_{-1}^{+1} y(x)\,dx \\
\int_{-1}^{+1} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2}\,dx = \pi \\ 
\mbox{maximize}_{y(x)} A
$$

Because $\pi$ is precisely the length of a semicircle of radius $1$ centered on the origin, it is intuitively clear that the maximizing curve is that semicircle.  In fact, if some other curve of the same length  yielded a larger area, then the familiar unrestricted isoperimetric problem would be maximized by that curve attached to its own reflection about the $X$ axis, and the answer would not be a circle. No calculus of variations needed.

Now the real problem:

> For $2 < L < \pi$, find the curve $y(x)$ of length $L$ going from $(x=-1,y=0)$ to $(x=+1,y=0)$ that maximizes the area between the curve and the $X$ axis:
>   $$A = \int_{-1}^{+1} y(x)\,dx \\
> \int_{-1}^{+1} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2}\,dx = L \\ 
> \mbox{maximize}_{y(x)} A
> $$

My intuition tells me that the answer will be a circular arc of the appropriate length, entered about some point on the negative $Y$ axis.  [Disclaimer -- my intuition could be wrong!] There may be a clever proof of this without using the calculus of variations,  but I'd like to see this problem tackled using the calculus of variations with the constraint realized via a Lagrange multiplier.

(The reason I specified that $L < \pi$ is to avoid the potential of messiness of double-valued functions going outside the $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ strip.)

Comment: Do you mean (as it seems) that start and end points are same?

Comment: Given the integration limits, it looks like curve goes from $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$ [rather than ending at $(-1,0)$ as stated in colored box]

Comment: Made the change -- I did mean +1 not $-1$ for the right endpoint.

Comment: With the endpoints distinct on the axis, it's (queen) Dido's problem. Wiki has notes, though I didn't immediately see one giving calculus of variation approach.

Answer (score 1):

In general, an extremum of $I(y) = \int_a^b F(x,y,y') dx$ amongst all $C^2$ functions $y$ with $y(a)=A, y(b)=B$, $J(y) = \int_a^b G(x,y,y') dx = L$ is an extremal of $$K(y)  = \int_a^b F + \lambda G dx$$ for some constant $\lambda$ - a Lagrange multiplier, as you say. You can find the details of the Lagrange multiplier argument worked out in Gelfand and Fomin's book on Calculus of Variations (iirc), or on p.14 [here](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~jmf/Teaching/Lectures/CoV.pdf), or [here](https://www.math.byu.edu/~bakker/Math521/Lectures/M521Lec39.pdf)

In your case the new functional $K$ is $\int_{-1}^1 y + \lambda \sqrt{1+y'^2} dx$. You can look for extremals in the usual way: [Beltrami's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_identity) is

$$ y + \lambda \sqrt{1+y'^2} - \lambda y'^2 / \sqrt{1+y'^2} = C$$ for some constant C, and if you tidy up and solve it you get the equation of a circle with centre on the $y$-axis at height $\sqrt{\lambda^2-1}$ and radius $\lambda$, where
$$ L = |2 \lambda \sin^{-1}(1/\lambda)|$$

You can avoid the arc length issue by working in polar coordinates - for bigger $L$ the solution will still be a circle, but $y$ won't be expressible as a function of $x$.